# SPSS permissions to write to file

Tags: file, permissions, save, handle, spss

I am using file handles to write my datasets to file in spss, which worked fine the first time.

```
FILE HANDLE directoryPath /NAME='D:\XX\Dropbox\XX\' . 
FILE HANDLE write_data /NAME='directoryPath/dataset_1.sav' . 
SAVE OUTFILE='write_data '
```

Now I get the following error:

```
>Error # 5332 in column 26.  Text: write_data
>The specified file or directory is read-only and cannot be written to.  The 
>file will not be saved.  Save the file with another name or to a different 
>location or change the access permissions first. 
>Execution of this command stops.
```

If I specify the full path rather than the file handle:

```
 SAVE OUTFILE='D:\XX\Dropbox\XX\dataset_1.sav' 
 /COMPRESSED.
```

It works fine. As you can see, i am writing to a dropbox folder. I am not sure if this interferes with the permissions. Is there anyone that knows how to make my file handle example work by changing overall permissions, or do I need to revert back to changing my syntax manually?

Answer (score 0):

File handles are not cumulative.  Only the first portion can be interpreted as a file handle.

Comment: They can be used like this. See the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966177/specifying-relative-paths-in-spss-18